# Dropdown not filling when attempting to bind with ajax and controller action

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to fill a dropdown using ajax and a controller action, but nothing seems to be happening when I click the button that triggers the action:

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetBranch", "Report")',
            type: "GET",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#dropdown2").append('<option value=' + result.BranchId + '>' + result.BranchName + '</option>');
            }
        });
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult GetBranch()
    {
        var branch = new Branch();
        var branchId = branch.BranchId;
        var branchName = branch.BranchName;

        return Json(new[]
        {
            new {Id = branchId, Value = branchName}
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is a practice I am not too familiar with so there could be something obvious missing. None of the answers here have been able to help me because I am trying to bind to an existing `<select>`; not a `@DropdownListFor`

It seems that the controller action is not getting hit with the ajax call, so nothing is getting returned.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure "nothing is happening", have you debugged server and client code? Are you getting any exceptions? Have you looked in the network tab of the browser dev tools to see if a request is being made?

Comment: The controller action is not getting hit by the Ajax call. i did make sure that the ajax block is getting hit in the client code though

Comment: Can you show your route config?

Comment: So can you see the ajax request being made in the network tab or in fiddler? What kind of response are you getting?

Comment: Just tried, I am getting a 404, but the Controller Action and Controller Name are correct

Comment: since your ajax call is sending a get, make sure that your controller is looking for a get.  fixing a 404 is really just looking at the details and trying to make sure that every part matches.  for the drop down you will need to do an $.each on the result and add them to the drop down one at a time

Comment: It hits the controller action when in a script tag in the view, but not in external js. But it is just returning an `undefined`

Comment: Thats a separate issue in itself though. Stepping through my controller to figure it out

Comment: @cfly24, so in separate js file you have no way to resolve this `'@Url.Action("GetBranch", "Report")'`. ASP.NET MVC rendering engine does not process external js files. So you need to have this resolved on the view, and then use in external js.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public JsonResult GetBranch()
    {

    var branch = new Branch();
    var branchs = new List<Branch>();
    var branchId = "Branch01"; //If only your branch id datatype is string
    branch.branchId = branchId;
    var branchName = "Name of Branch";//Name you want to give for your branch
    branch.branchName = branchName;
    branchs.Add(branch);
        return Json(branchs.Select(t => new {Text = t.branchName, Value = t.branchId}), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```